# Cleaner way for defining Angular templates

Tags: javascript, angularjs

#### Consider this code

```
my_app.run( [ '$templateCache' , function( $templateCache ) {
    var template = "" +
        "{{ item.name }}" +
        "<ul ng-if='item.sub'>" +
            "<li ng-repeat='item in item.sub' ng-include=\"'angular-multi-select-item.htm'\"></li>" +
        "</ul>" +
        "";
    $templateCache.put( 'angular-multi-select-item.htm' , template );
}]);
```

While this works as expected, I see it quite ugly (the concatenated string with html inside). Is there some other, more clean, way to define the html for an Angular template?

Answer (score 2):

What you think about this? Just create a view html view file in your working directory and load it with `$http`.

```
$templateCache.put('angular-multi-select-item.htm', $http.get('views/template.html'));
```

Your can also try it with `ng-include? ([documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude)) and add includes in the main view like:

```
<div ng-include="'views/template.html'"></div>
```

Comment: Ah, indeed. I knew about that one, but this has several disadvantages. I can't control where the template will be (consider a big project managed with npm/bower). Also, it will make as many extra http calls as the number of templates I have. (which could get up to 10 easily, which, imho, is quite expensive). Nevertheless, I'll vote up :)

Comment: Ok, but how would I load the template if I don't know where it is?

Comment: Let me try again. Let's say I'm working with a framework that manages libraries with NPM or Bower. Now let's say my library (which includes the view) is installed in `project_root/libraries/npm/my_library/view.html`. How would I know that my view was saved there?

Comment: Your answer wasn't what I was asking for, I think I already explained why. I up-voted it because it will probably solve somebody else's problem. NPM and Bower packages are exactly the same thing, it depends of the package's code if it can be used inside the browser.

Comment: You're starting to mix quite some things here. NPM is a package manager that happens to be shipped with Node. Nothing more, nothing less. Try to install a package with Bower and NPM. You'll end up  having the exact same files (most probably). As I said, a package installed by Bower or NPM is usable in the browser only if the package itself was designed that way. And, last but not least important, I'm not using Node (which you pulled here from thin air), I'm using Yii2, which manages frontend deps with both NPM and Bower.